# Google satellite Image_Features

Tags: google-maps, labeling, features, image

What is the method to close labels and features on satellite images of Google maps?

**NOTE:** I don't want to use classic version of google map or use of history of google map.

What i want to remove or close, are shown in given example image.

[image: Example Image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Google Static-Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro) to style a satellite image without any labels and features, if that is what you are looking for. The API returns an image based on the url parameters. The API requires you to create an API key to be able to use it, but you can get one for free. The free API key is bound to a [usage limit](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/usage-limits):

> - Free until exceeding 25,000 map loads per 24 hours for 90 consecutive days.
> - 640 x 640 maximum image resolution

You are looking for the *maptype* parameter:

> - **roadmap** (default): specifies a standard roadmap image, as is normally shown on the Google Maps website. If no maptype value is specified, the Google Static Maps API serves roadmap tiles by default.
> - **satellite**: specifies a satellite image.
> - **terrain**: specifies a physical relief map image, showing terrain and vegetation.
> - **hybrid**: specifies a hybrid of the satellite and roadmap image, showing a transparent layer of major streets and place names on the satellite image.

Your url will look like this:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=LOCATION&maptype=satellite&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

You can also use the *style* parameter to adjust how the image is displayed, which gives you a bit more freedom.